# Expiation for hurting others

Tags: forgiveness

Asalamu Alaikum!

I hurt many people in my life and I regret it a lot. I feel very sad about it and I’m trying to be different now but I feel like there is this huge burden on me. Will Allah ever forgive me if I make du’a for them always? And if I make dua and do good deeds on their behalf will they be accepted and compensated for what I did? Will I be punished for this or no? I don’t know some of them and some don’t know about it, and some I cannot contact so that is why. Is this okay?

Jazakallah Khair.

Answer (score 0):

This is for Allah to say and will depend on the kind of hurt and injustice that you exposed others to and whether your repentance is sincere or not - after all - some people knowing that Allah is *rahmat* snd *rahim* - repent only by their lips - and not in the heart.

You will find out on Judgement Day.

For 'Allah, is Knowing, Wise' whereas men and women are mortal and finite creatures who often err.